# Вопрос по падежам

Tags: падежи

Скажите пожалуйста почему в предложении:
*Георгий поинтересовался, сколько лет Татьяне Петровне* местоимение употреблено в именительном падеже, а в предложении:
*Что же подарить Илье Ефимовичу* местоимение употреблено не в именительном падеже. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Что же подарить Илье Ефимовичу. местоимение употреблено не в именительном падеже. ?
```

Подарить кого? что? - винительный падеж

Comment: Людмила, автор спрашивает про **местоимения**? O_o? Вы уверены, что поняли вопрос??? Я - нет.

Comment: Почему ж не поняла? Сколько-им.п., что же -вин.п.

Comment: Да? сильно... Чувствую себя полным идиотом.... Не знаю даже, смеяться или плакать.

Answer (score 0):

Это не местоимения, а собственные имена существительные.

В первом случае "Георгий" это подлежащее, так как Георгий совершает действие(Георгий *поинтересовался*) -> отвечает на вопрос **кто?** => кто?/что? -- Именительный падеж.

"Что же подарить(**кому?->**) Илье Ефимовичу."

кому?/чему? -- Дательный падеж.